# GenericListCellRenderer example: add data to existing list?

Tags: codenameone

I use the example [GenericListCellRenderer](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/list/GenericListCellRenderer.html)

and cannot find to add a data object to the current list.
And the next were to delete a data from the list.
How may I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First let me start by repeating our recommendation that you [don't do that](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html). There are better alternatives.

You need to use a model with map data as explained in the component section of the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_list).

Comment: I read these article "don't do that" and looked into the developer guide before. But there are a lot of samples to create a view with data in it.
F.e. DefaultListModel, Multilistsample.java, Infinite Scroll Container
so what should I use for lets say string, string, image map?
I found a good sample  for to do a multi list, but "don't do that"!?

Comment: Or is it a good idea to use a defaulttablemodel , good for editing, adding cells and save it to storage by tableobject?

Comment: Table isn't a list. There are samples of alternatives in the article. Pretty much all of our demos don't use list...